# If $\dim(A/\mathfrak p)=\dim(A)-1$, then is $\mathfrak p$ principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal in $A$. When is it true that if $\dim(A/\mathfrak p)=\dim(A)-1$ then $\mathfrak p$ is a principal ideal in $A$?

I'm pretty sure $A$ must be at least an integral domain, and I'm pretty sure that I have a proof when it's a *UFD* (in that case $\mathfrak p$ must be a minimal nonzero prime, and therefore principal). The question is related to the question of whether or not every codimension $1$ subvariety of an irreducible variety is a complete intersection.

Comment: It is not true. Take $A =k[[x,y,z]]/(x^2-yz)$ and $p = (x,y)$. Then $\dim A = 2$ and $\dim A/p = \dim k[[z]] = 1$. However, $p$ is not principal.

Comment: If all height one primes are principal in a Noetherian domain, then it is a UFD. So, most of the time, you need a UFD.